# Is $\cos(x[n])$ stable?

Tags: stability

I am highly confused about the stability of $\cos(x[n])$.

If we provide a bounded input such as $x[n]=u[n]$, the output is bounded.

Now if we provide an unbounded signal $x[n]=\delta[n]$, the output oscillates between $-1$ and $1$. So I think it's marginally stable in this case.

Am I correct? I have this confusion because in my book it says it's *unstable* when $x[n]=\delta[n]$. So my questions are: Is the function BIBO stable and also is it stable for an unbounded input ?

Note: $u[n]$ and $\delta[n]$ are unit step and dirac delta functions respectively.

---

**Correction**: As mentioned in the comment, $x[n]=\delta[n]$ is bounded too.

But this points more strongly to $\cos(x[n])$ being stable, isn't it?

Comment: I think your question is a bit ill-defined: If your $\delta[n]$ is the pulse we typically use in *discrete* signal processing, it's very much bounded at any point in $n$-space. If you, on the other hand, use the quasi-continuous *distribution* $\delta(t)$, the cosine of that for $t=0$ is undefined, because the value of $\delta(0)$ is undefined. So, not the appropriate way of testing this.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I suppose I got a bit confused with $\delta(t)$ and $\delta[n]$, I used to think that both are $\infty$ at $t,n=0$. So in the question let's consider the correct definition of $\delta[n]$, which is bounded.

Comment: but that makes no sense, either! If you just input a bounded value into $\cos$, what will you learn? (especially, how can you conclude that "it points to $\cos$ being stable"??)

Comment: The question is (a bit more) ill defined because $\cos$ is a signal. Stability is the property of a system. If the "system" is $y[n]=cos(x[n])$, then it has no feedback from $y[n]$ which could put it into some form of oscillation. It is a "simple" lookup table that maps $0..\pi \rightarrow 1..-1$. Why would this "oscillate"? And especially when all that you do is pass an impulse to it. The system will "pulse" its output too and return to zero (?)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Can't we learn about the BIBO stability of $\cos(x[n])$

Comment: @paulplusx see A_A's comment! As said, all this is ill-defined; what I meant with "what do we learn from inserting the (bounded) $\delta[n]$?" was that you'd best case see the impulse response of your system; but: as you can see, that's a bounded, non-recursive system, so "stability" is of no concern, and I really wonder what you're asking...

Comment: @A_A I apologize for the confusion but $y[n]=\cos(x[n])$ is a system and all I am looking for is BIBO stability.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I got this question from my book and it asks whether the system $y[n]=\cos(x[n])$ is stable or not and in the solution it uses $x[n]=\delta[n]$ and then says  $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(k)|<\infty$ is violated and concludes the system is not stable.

Comment: wait, where does that $h$ come from?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Exactly, that's why I am even more confused :-( There is no mention of impulse response in the question.

Comment: so, seriously, you're sitting in front of a book that we don't have, and are citing formulas that use symbols that have nothing to do with the symbols you use in your question: How are we supposed to help then? Anyway, a non-recursive system cannot become unstable.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am really sorry for being so a vague. I think your last sentence is my answer. As I want to know if it's BIBO stable, all I can observe is for bounded inputs like unit step or dirac delta, the output is bounded(which is enough for BIBO). I just wanted to know whether my thinking is correct or not, that's all. You may very well close the question as "unclear" if it's still not answerable or if it is answerable, I request you to simply verify my BIBO claim :)

Comment: Well, no, I can't verify your claim: the BIBO aspect can't answered by testing with a single bounded input.

Comment: @MarcusMüller but the output of $\cos$ will always be bounded for any input, bounded or unbounded, isn't that right?

Comment: Well, yes, but you **really** don't need me to confirm that, do you?

Comment: @MarcusMüller No, but since, the output is **always bounded**, doesn't it make the given system BIBO stable?

Comment: again, you know that, why are you asking me to confirm? You even have books where exactly that is written?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Please don't misunderstand me. Yes, I know that but because my book proved just opposite of what I am saying (without proper explanation) I am confused and that is why I need someone's verification.

Comment: No need for apologies don't worry about it. The point here is to have a clear question that can (hopefully) be answered. Maybe posting the original passage from the book would help too (?)

Comment: @A_A Thank you for understanding. I have actually put out everything that is there in my book in a compact form in one of the comments addressing Marcus. The problem is that my book is not using a clear solution and is using context that is not present in the question which is why I was so confused.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84141/discussion-on-question-by-paulplusx-is-cosxn-stable).

Comment: I think we have an answer. The system just flagged this post as having too many comments....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The I/O relation
$$y[n] = \cos(x[n])$$

represents a **stable** system.

Because by definition of $\cos(x)$, irrespective of the input $x[n]$, its output will always be bounded by $$-1 \leq \cos(x[n]) \leq 1 $$ for all $x[n]$ for all $n$. Even if $x[n]$ is undefined ( such as would be the case with $x[n] = 1/n$ at $n=0$ as Marcus pointed out) we for sure know that the system output is bounded (the value of input is undefined, but the output is known to be within $\pm1$.)